# apache poi, NPE

Tags: java, apache-poi

my main looks like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] agrv) throws IOException{


            Sheet AdditveWs=inputWb.getSheet("Additive List");
            int r1=AdditveWs.getLastRowNum()+1;
            list1=new AdditiveInformation[r1]; 
            fillAddInfoObj(AdditveWs,r1,list1);

            finalOutput(list1);

    }
```

the fillAddInfoObj(AdditveWs,r1,list1) looks like this:

```
public static void fillAddInfoObj(Sheet ws, int r,AdditiveInformation[] list1) throws IOException{

    System.out.println(r);
    list1=new AdditiveInformation[r];

    for(int i=0;i<r;i++){
        Row row=ws.getRow(i);
        list1[i]=new AdditiveInformation();
        list1[i].readAdditiveName(row);

    }


}
```

and finally the finalOutput(list1) looks like this:

```
public static void finalOutput(AdditiveInformation[] list1){

        **for(AdditiveInformation x: list1)**
            x.output();
    }
```

I'm getting a java null point exception on the starred line in the finalOutput() function, 
can anyone tell me why?

Comment: sorry the npe is coming at the line x.output();

Comment: Then edit the post accordingly ;) It means there are null elements in your array.

Comment: finalOuput method only iterating the list,It can't through null pointer exception.I guess you need to paste stack trace

Comment: when i print the stack trace, it points to the same line; 
when i call the output() function in fillAddInfoObj() function it works perfectly, i dont know why its not working when i call it to the finalOutput() function

Comment: OT: Is there any reason why you reinitialize list1?

Comment: @DirkLachowski
no that was a mistake